# How to allow insert multiple paragraph inside content control using Word javascript api

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, word-addins, javascript-api-for-office

I am inserting a nested content control and want to insert multiple paragraph in inner cc. There is a outer cc that is not editable and inside it, another inner CC is available in which i want to insert multiple paragraph on return key press. But currently i can insert only text in inner CC, enter(return) key is not inserting another para. Please advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you operating from UI or through API? on word rich client or word online? Right now if you try to insert multiple paragraph into an inline content control(content control inside one paragraph), it is not allowed. Only block content control(content control cross several paragraphs) allows inserting multiple paragraph.

Comment: I am using API for inserting the contentControls, want to add multiple para through word on enter key.

Comment: You should avoid asking a question as part of an answer.